# Looking for story title of a young girl with enhanced robot cat who becomes queen of the asteroid belt

Tags: story-identification, robots

Her parents are separated and leave her to her own devices.  Her father was a genius who studied swarm tactics and upgraded her pet robot cat.  With her cat's help she runs away to a work colony in the asteroid belt, where a revolution soon takes place and she ends up the leader.

I read this story around 2010 to 2013.  I hope I'm not combining more than one story.  I'd sure like to read it again.

Ring a bell, anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably [Accelerando](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerando) by Charles Stross, or possibly "Halo", one of the stories that made it up (the novel was a fix-up of stories which were individually serialized earlier).

Summary of "Halo" from the Wikipedia page:

> A decade later, Amber Macx —now in her early teens— finally breaks free from her domineering mother by utilising a complex plot, thought up by Manfred and Annette, in which she enslaves herself via a Yemeni shell corporation and later enlists aboard a Franklin Collective-owned, youth-crewed spacecraft, mining materials from Amalthea, Jupiter's third moon. Pamela petitions the imam Sadeq to issue an Islamic legal judgment against Amber, which she thwarts by setting up her own empire on a small, privately owned asteroid, thus making herself sovereign. In the meantime, the alien signals have been decoded, and a physical journey to a mentioned "router" is planned.

The series as a whole are linked by the members of the Macx family who are accompanied (and perhaps in some instances guided by) Aineko, a robotic cat that Manfred Macx upgraded early on and later began upgrading itself.

The author made the entire novel available on his website for free in a variety of ebook formats, so you can check it out [here](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/fiction/accelerando/accelerando-intro.html) if you'd like.

Comment: Could you add some details to back this up?

Comment: Yeah, in the process.

Comment: Don't be postin' no steenkin' stubs

Comment: Well, this’ll be hitting HNQ. ;)

Comment: Wow!  StarPilotSix, that's it.  Thanks.  And I have "Accelerando" on my Kindle.

Comment: I earlier spent a couple of hours  trying to search my Kindle files, but without success.  I thought it might have been in a magazine and went off on a big Red Herring about Kindle magazines not being searchable on the cloud version... so I dug out my actual Kindle, recharged it and "accelerando" came up in the search but I was now focused on the magazines.  Live and learn.  Thanks again.